# Change color polygons by area of polygons

Tags: qgis

I have polygons with the area in the attribute table and I want change polygons to red color if they have area less 70.

[image: area and polygon]

Comment: Thank you for help, yes is also a GOOD answer, if I want to save the changes in GeoJSON, can I do it or I need to create an attribute table different column and save the color by a polygon?

Comment: is help me and useful, I just try to learn more about this program.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I noticed that the feature in the top-left of your screenshot looks like it has self-intersecting boundaries, which would make it an invalid geometry.

Answer (score 7):

Create a rule based symbology like this:
One with the rule `"area" < 70` and one with the rule `ELSE`
(`"area"` refers to an attribute value while `$area` calculates the area; use the one you need; according to your sceenshot it is `"area"`)

[image]

Comment: @EvgenyRyvkin you can also use a graduated renderer on the $area variable (rather than a SHAPE_AREA column), then set your own class breaks and colours.

Answer (score 5):

*Here's another method. It's not really any better than MrXsquared's answer, but I had already started writing it.*

**Use data-defined settings to control fill color**

[image]

with this expression: 
`if("area"<70, '#ff0000','#00ff00')`

This expression will set the fill color to red (#ff0000 in hex notation) when the area is less than 70, and green otherwise.

[image]

If you want to use different shades of red and green, you can get the hex notation for the desired color from the "select color" dialog - just select the color you want and scroll down to find the hex notation near the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes is a good example of how can I write different color in hexa and using data-defined.